# An infinite binary word is a string $(a_1,\cdots,a_n,\cdots)$ where $a_n \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: combinatorics

An infinite binary word is a string $(a_1,\cdots,a_n,\cdots)$ where $a_n \in \{0,1\}$.Fix a word $s$ such that $s=(s_1 s_2 \cdots)$ such that $s_p=1$ where $p$ is a prime.Then what is the cardinality of the set $E=\{a: \text{ there is m} s.t. a_n=s_n \forall n \ge m \}$

My claim is that the set $E$ is unaccountable.

When $n=1$ then $a=s$

When $n=2$ then $a =(a_1,s_2,s_3,\cdots)$ such that $a_1 \ne s_1$. The only possible choice is $1$.

When $n=3$ then $a=(a_1,a_2,s_3,\cdots)$ for this $a$ to be different from the above two we need $a_2 \ne s_2$.So wr have two choices.

When $n=4$ then $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,s_4,\cdots)$ for this $a$ to be different from the above two we need $a_3 \ne s_3$.So we have $2^2$ choices.

Going on this way we can claim that the set is uncountable. Is my approach okay?

Comment: It seems that in fact your description of what happens for each case of $n$ is actually a proof that the set is countable.  For each $n$, as you suggest, there are only finitely many items in $E$.  So, you can enumerate all of $E$ by counting up the elements for $n=1$, then for $n=2$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct. Let $E_m=\{a: a_n=s_n \, \forall n \geq m\}$. Then $E_m$ has at most $2^{m-1}$ elements and $E =\bigcup_n E_m$. So $E$ is countable.

Countable union of countable sets is countable. In particular, Countable union of finite sets is countable.